# VSCode and PHP with XDebug and PHP Debug extension and IISExpress

Tags: php, visual-studio-code, xdebug, iis-express

I am trying to use the PHP Debug extension in VS Code. I have followed the instructions and pasted the phpinfo contents into the wizard and downloaded the appropriate dll. I get the following error

**launch.json**

```
"version": "0.2.0",
"configurations": [
    {
        "name": "Listen for XDebug",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "port": 9000,
        "log": true
        },
    {
        "name": "Launch currently open script",
        "type": "php",
        "request": "launch",
        "program": "${file}",
        "cwd": "${fileDirname}",
        "port": 9000
    }
]
```

**php.ini**

```
[XDEBUG]
zend_extension = C:\PHP\ext\php_xdebug-2.9.6-7.4-vc15-nts.dll
xdebug.remote_enable = 1
xdebug.remote_autostart = 1
xdebug.remote_handler = dbgp
xdebug.remote_host = 127.0.0.1
xdebug.remote_port = 9000
xdebug.remote_mode = req
```

If I choose the listen option having previousy started IISExpress I get this error

> Error: listen EACCES: permission denied 0.0.0.0:9000
> at Server.setupListenHandle [as _listen2] (net.js:1211:19)
> at listenInCluster (net.js:1276:12)
> at Server.listen (net.js:1364:7)
> at c:\Users\me.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0\out\phpDebug.js:236:24
> at new Promise ()
> at createServer (c:\Users\me.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0\out\phpDebug.js:184:40)
> at PhpDebugSession. (c:\Users\me.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0\out\phpDebug.js:240:27)
> at Generator.next ()
> at c:\Users\me.vscode\extensions\felixfbecker.php-debug-1.13.0\out\phpDebug.js:7:71
> at new Promise () {   code: 'EACCES',   errno: 'EACCES',   syscall: 'listen',   address: '0.0.0.0',   port: 9000 }

If I choose the other option and start VS Code first, I get an IISExpress error

> Failed to register URL "http://localhost:9000/" for site
> "XXXXXXX-0f34f450-230f-4d11-8878-1a90a024dcf6" application "/".
> Error description: The process cannot access the file because it is
> being used by another process. (0x80070020)

I know port 9000 is not used because if I run this command when nothing is running it shows nothing running

```
Get-Process -Id (Get-NetTCPConnection -LocalPort 9000).OwningProcess
```

Clearly both sides can start port 9000 but they are not happy sharing the same port. What am I missing?

Comment: *"Clearly both sides can start port 9000 but they are not happy sharing the same port. What am I missing?"* Correct -- you misunderstand how Xdebug works and what that port is for. Please check Xdebug docs for that -- https://xdebug.org/docs/remote#communication (with animated pics)

Comment: **In short:** 1) Xdebug does not listen any ports. It's the one that connects to debug client (VSCode in your case) and NOT other way around. 2) You CANNOT start website/webserver on Xdebug port ... as VSCode will not be able to listen for Xdebug connections then. You need to use another port for website (e.g. 80, 8000, 800x etc).

Comment: I have tried other ports. Nothing is using port 9000 as I demonstrated when I run the Get-Process cmdlet. I want to start IISExpress first, when I do the site works perfect on localhost:9000 but XDebug gives a permission denied error so I can't debug.

Comment: Let me try again. DO NOT run your website on 9000 port. Period. Run it on 8000 or some another. 9000 port must be used by VSCode ONLY (as this is where Xdebug will try to connect to).

Comment: But 9000 is the default! I have happily run on 9000 on other machines, unsurprisingly as it is the default. https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=felixfbecker.php-debug

Comment: Once again: Web server port IS NOT THE SAME as Xdebug port. They HAVE to be different. VSCode is the one that MUST be listening on Xdebug port. If that port is already used by a web server, then VSCode CANNOT listen for Xdebug connections and debugger will fail with an error. You MUST configure your IIS Express to use different port than 9000. Alternatively: use different port for Xdebug (e.g. 9001). But once again: it has to be different to a web server port.

Comment: ok thanks, I see what you are saying now. I will give that a go. Thanks for keeping on at me!

Answer (score 1):

My mistake was the site was also running on the port 9000. It needs to be a completely different port to XDebug which listens on its own port.

**iisexpress.json**

```
{
  "port": 1785,
  "path": "C:\\YourSite",
  "clr": "v4.0",
  "protocol": "http"
}
```